# Making custom changes to CP language

Tags: craft3, control-panel, language

I want to change a few words in the CP (Craft 3). What's the best way to do it, without being overwritten by a Craft update if possible...?

I was thinking about creating my own language file, but can't find the complete method to do so, and it might still be affected by an update? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just create *translations/en/app.php* directory of your Craft installation with the following content (replace `en` with the desired language code):

```
<?php return [
    'Settings' => ' Params',
];
```

Craft updates won't touch it.

Comment: oh great, ok. Do I have to add all the variables in my file or which language is the failover if the variable doesn't exist? Also how can I name my language to make available in the languages dropdown list for the admin user?

Comment: You don't have to list all strings in your file. Craft will happily fall back to using the default ones, defined in _translations/<lang_code>/app.php_ (where `<lang_code>`) is the language code of the language chosen by the current user. I'm pretty sure you cannot create new locale though. You have to stick to the one Craft already knows. See for the list of existing locales https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/translations